# Problema no Hover do scroll

Tags: css

Quando passo o mouse no botão e vejo o conteúdo não consigo usar a barra de rolagem, simplesmente oculta o conteúdo, alguém pode dar um help?

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:hover .mostrar {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mostrar {
  background: #CCC;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.conteudo-meio {
  width: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <section class="conteudo-meio">
      <a href="#">Passar o mouse no menu</a>
      <div class="mostrar">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <p>Item 6</p>
        <p>Item 7</p>
        <p>Item 8</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tentou comentar  linha: `overflow: hidden;` que está declarada 2x em `.mostrar`?

Comment: Sim testei aqui, mas não mudou nada.

Comment: quando executei o seu código, apareceu a barra de rolagem e o conteúdo...]

Comment: @JcSaint o problema é quando poem o mouse em cima da barra de rolagem, o conteúdo fecha.

Comment: Isso quando passa o mouse em cima da barra de rolagem, fecha o conteúdo, esse é o problema.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema, pra mim apareceu a barra de rolagem e se paro o mouse em cima da barra o conteúdo continua lá :/ estou usando Mozilla Firefox 52

Comment: O erro é no Chrome, firefox funcionou normal também

Comment: Samuel, clica no conteudo que ai "ativa" ele e você consegue fazer o scroll (talvez sabendo isso resolva o problema). EDIT: Na verdade funciona o scroll do mouse a barra mesmo nao dá rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz vários testes e a `div` continuava sumindo, até que personalizei a barra de rolagem e funcionou como esperado. Então como o problema é só no chrome, tu pode utilizar um `scrollbar` personalizado, tem várias formas de [detectar se o navegador é o chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome), segue um exemplo de `scrollbar`, personalizando ele a `div` não some.

```css
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:hover .mostrar {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mostrar {
  background: #CCC;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.conteudo-meio {
  width: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999999;
}


/* Let's get this party started */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <section class="conteudo-meio">
      <a href="#">Passar o mouse no menu</a>
      <div class="mostrar">
        <p>Item 1</p>
        <p>Item 2</p>
        <p>Item 3</p>
        <p>Item 4</p>
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <p>Item 6</p>
        <p>Item 7</p>
        <p>Item 8</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
</ul>
```